# The countable intersection of collections of which one is countable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

An assignment reads :

> Let $\Omega$ be a non-countable collection and let $\mathscr{A}=\{A\in\Omega\ |\ A\text{ is countable or }A^C \text{ is countable}\}$
>   Prove that $\mathscr{A}$ is a sigma-algebra.

It's only necessary to prove that (1) $\Omega\in\mathscr{A}$, (2) every complement of $A\in\mathscr{A}$ is in $\mathscr{A}$, and (3) every countable union $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$ of elements of $\mathscr{A}$ is in $\mathscr{A}$, too.

The first two conditions hold because $\emptyset$ is countable so $\emptyset^C=\Omega\in\mathscr{A}$, and because (2) is implied by the very defintion of $\mathscr{A}$.

The solution of the assignment then proceeds to show that (3) holds, too. If all the $A_n$ in the countable union are countable, then the countable union is countable too. If one of the $A_n$, say, $A_m$ is not countable, then $(\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n)^C=\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n^C$. Because $A_m^C$ is countable (otherwise $A_m$ would not be an element of $\mathscr{A}$), it follows that $\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n^C$ is countable because $\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n^C\subseteq A_m^C$.

I do not understand that very last claim, namely that $\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n^C\subseteq A_m^C$. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\in\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n^C$.  What does this actually mean?  It means that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x\in A_n^C$.  In particular, taking $n=m$, we see that $x\in A_m^C$.

So, every element of $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n^C$ is also an element of $A_m^C$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The elements in $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} A_n^C$ are the elements which are in *all* the sets $A_n^C$. More elaborately, they are the elements which you can find in $A_1^C$, *and* in $A_2^C$, *and* in $A_3^C$, ... So also, for any $m$, each element is also in $A_m^C$, i.e. it is a subset of $A_m^C$.